# Translating array included in the $_POST to MySql query in Yii Framework

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, yii

Im trying to solve my issue with Yii Framework. I have a view that returns a $_POST :

```
Array ( [Questions] => Array ( [countries] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [categories] => 1 ) [yt0] => Search )
```

Information like categories is single id, where countries is an array.

Now, my question is, how tu use properly the Yii model query builder so that I can include statement for many countries from an array.
Something 
like:

```
"SELECT questions.name from questions WHERE countries.id == $_Post['Questions']['countries'][ 0 ] AND countries.id == $_Post['Questions']['countries'][ 1 ] AND .... + n times for countries"
```

When $_POST['Questions']['countries'] was returning only one id i used the following :

```
  $model = Questions::model()->with( 

                array(  'countries' => array (
                          'select' => 'name',
                          'condition' => 'countries.id=:cou_id', // How to do for array?
                          'params' => array (':cou_id' => $_POST["Questions"]["countries"]) // How to do for array ? 
                        ) 
                )

        )->findAll(array ('select' => 'question'));
```

How to do for multiple countries ? How to include foreach loop with the Yii:model query builder ?! Pls help.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately the `condition` property of the criteria needs to include a fragment that uses the MySql [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function, e.g. `countries.id IN (x, y, z, ...)`. You can do that manually, but Yii provides the convenience method [`CDbCriteria::addInCondition`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail) to help:

```
$countryCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
$countryCriteria->select = 'name';
$countryCriteria->addInCondition('id', $_POST["Questions"]["countries"]);

$model = Questions::model()->with(array('countries' => $countryCriteria))
                           ->findAll(array('select' => 'question'));
```

Comment: Hey, u were close, but not exact. I have solved my issue trying to combine what u said with some info on net.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works :

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(); 
$criteria->with = array('countries');
$criteria->addInCondition('countries.id' , $_POST['Questions']['countries']);
$model = Questions::model()->findAll($criteria);
```